# Uncertain of cause of Mailchimp::ListNotSubscribedError

Tags: mailchimp

A couple times a week our team receives a `Mailchimp::ListNotSubscribedError` from the mailchimp API.  I have not been able to determine from the help or anywhere else what situation causes this error. Any ideas? We use v2 via the mailchimp-api gem.

Answer (score 0):

This error was occurred since you try to update/unsubscribe an email which does not belong to that list.
Please check if the email exists in that list by [this method.](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php)

Comment: this is not quite an accurate description of the error, which is what had been throwing me off.  If the email has never been subscribed to the list, a different email doesn't exist error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

After some back-and-forth with Mailchimp support, apparently this error is thrown if:

1. you are trying to update a subscription in v2 Mailchimp api *and*
2. a user has him/herself unsubscribed to the list *or* Mailchimp has manually 'cleaned' them from the list because their email was undeliverable.